# How to create a 3D cuboid with gradient color in it with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I have basic knowlege in HTML,CSS. I want to create a HTML page with these  3 3D cuboid like this

[image]
The 3D cuboid in above image looks complex to me. So could anybody suggestion how to create this 3D cuboids with HTML and CSS

To create first cuboid i have tried this:

```
<div class="box1">
      <div>step 1</div>
      <div>Your Title</div>
      <div></div>                                                
</div>
```

I have added 3 `div` inside main `div` that represent faces of cuboid. Below is the css:

```
.box1 {
  margin:50px;
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  perspective: 300px;
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:100px;
  color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
}
.box1 > div:first-child{
  width:30%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#008ec2b0,#085c6d);
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
    transform-origin: right;
}
.box1 > div:last-child {
  width:60%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,,#15a5c4,#4dca75);
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.box1 > div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  width:60%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#008ec2b0,#085c6d);
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
  transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

But unable to align the bottom of the cuboid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with perspective and transformation to create such shapes.

Here is an example for the second box:

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  perspective: 300px;
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:100px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
  
}
.box > div:first-child {
  width:60%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#f57300,orange);
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
    transform-origin: right;
    
}
.box > div:last-child {
  width:40%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,orange,#e53800);
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
  transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div>Your Title</div>
<div>30</div>
</div>
```

For the first and third one you may consider using a pseudo element to have the third face and add some `skew` transformation to have a perfect shape.

Here an example for the third box

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  perspective: 300px;
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:100px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
  position:relative;
  
}
.box > div:first-child {
  width:60%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#f57300,orange);
  transform: rotateY(-30deg) skewY(9deg);
    transform-origin: right;
    
}
.box > div:last-child {
  width:40%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,orange,#e53800);
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
  transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(30deg) skewY(-9deg);
}

.box:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -27px;
    width: 41%;
    left: 50px;
    height: 16px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,orange,#e53800);
    transform: rotate(4.6deg) skewX(-80deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div>Your Title</div>
<div>30</div>
</div>
```

Here is an example for the first one

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  perspective: 300px;
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:100px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
  position:relative;
  
}
.box > div:first-child {
  width:60%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#f57300,orange);
  transform: rotateY(-30deg) skewY(-9deg);
    transform-origin: right;
    
}
.box > div:last-child {
  width:40%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,orange,#e53800);
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
  transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(30deg) skewY(9deg);
}

.box:before {
        content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 91px;
    width: 29%;
    left: 50px;
    height: 22px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,orange,#e53800);
    transform: rotate(4.6deg) skewX(-80deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div>Your Title</div>
<div>30</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks . This is the type of answer i am expecting

Comment: I am facing issue with creating 1st cuboid. I have added 3 `div` inside main `div`. i was able to create 2 faces of cuboid but not able to create/align bottom portion of cuboid. Can you give me some suggestion

Comment: @AjayDev yes the first and the third are more tricky, Will update my answer ;)

Comment: I have updated my question as it has been put on hold

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just did a small example to let you know how to play with perspective in css html.

https://jsfiddle.net/ty820kbh/1

You can change the width and height of each faces in the CSS (stay coherent) and add the desired style then you can modify the perspective of `.wrapper` to show your cuboid in the view you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried to draw the desired cuboid with your example . i did not able to do it. as i have basic knowledge in css